# bigbluebutton <Failed to archive events for>...<Permission denied>

Tags: ffmpeg, red5, freeswitch, bigbluebutton

---

Hello i have a BigBlueButton (0.9.0-beta (622)) installation on Debian Wheezy (7.8) all is ok except archiving recordings...

in the log (/var/log/bigbluebutton/archive-488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675.log) i have always same message :

```
I, [2015-03-06T11:48:19.320704 #4550]  INFO -- : Archiving events for 488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675.
W, [2015-03-06T11:48:19.851280 #4550]  WARN -- : Failed to archive events for 488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675. Permission denied - /var/bigbluebutton/recording/raw/488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675/events.xml (complete error below...)
```

but all directory are writable by right user (tomcat7).

More Info:

bbb packages installed

```
ii  bbb-apps                              0.9.0-1ubuntu88               amd64        BigBlueButton applications for Red5
ii  bbb-apps-deskshare                    0.9.0-1ubuntu25               amd64        BigBlueButton deskshare module for Red5
ii  bbb-apps-sip                          0.9.0-1ubuntu19               amd64        BigBlueButton SIP module for Red5
ii  bbb-apps-video                        0.9.0-1ubuntu18               amd64        BigBlueButton video module for Red5
ii  bbb-client                            0.9.0-1ubuntu235              all          BigBlueButton Flash client
ii  bbb-config                            0.9.0-1ubuntu42               all          BigBlueButton configuration
rc  bbb-demo                              0.9.0-1ubuntu8                amd64        BigBlueButton API demos
ii  bbb-freeswitch                        0.9.0-1ubuntu38               amd64        BigBlueButton build of FreeSWITCH 1.5.x
ii  bbb-mkclean                           0.8.7-1                       amd64        tool to clean and optimize Matroska and WebM files
ii  bbb-office                            0.9.0-1ubuntu6                amd64        BigBlueButton wrapper for LibreOffice
ii  bbb-playback-presentation             0.9.0-1ubuntu11               amd64        BigBluebutton playback of presentation
ii  bbb-record-core                       0.9.0-1ubuntu37               amd64        BigBlueButton record and playback
ii  bbb-red5                              0.9.0-1ubuntu25               amd64        The Red5 server for bbb
ii  bbb-swftools                          0.9.2-1ubuntu14               amd64        The swftools files for bbb
ii  bbb-web                               0.9.0-1ubuntu54               all          BigBlueButton API
ii  bigbluebutton                         0.9.0-1ubuntu2                amd64        Open source web conferencing platform (bbb)
```

---

bbb-conf --check

```
BigBlueButton Server 0.9.0-beta (622)
                    Kernel version: 3.16.0-4-amd64(64-bit)
                            Memory: 12044 MB

/var/www/bigbluebutton/client/conf/config.xml (bbb-client)
        Port test (tunnel): 2xx.xxx.xxx.xx
                              Red5: 2xx.xxx.xxx.xx
              useWebrtcIfAvailable: true

/opt/freeswitch/conf/sip_profiles/external.xml (FreeSWITCH)
                    websocket port: 5066
                    WebRTC enabled: true

/etc/nginx/sites-available/bigbluebutton (nginx)
                       server name: 2xx.xxx.xxx.xx
                              port: 80
                    bbb-client dir: /var/www/bigbluebutton

/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/bigbluebutton/WEB-INF/classes/bigbluebutton.properties (bbb-web)
                      bbb-web host: 2xx.xxx.xxx.xx

/usr/share/red5/webapps/bigbluebutton/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml (red5)
                  voice conference: FreeSWITCH
                     capture video: true
                   capture desktop: true

/usr/local/bigbluebutton/core/scripts/bigbluebutton.yml (record and playback)
                     playback host: 2xx.xxx.xxx.xx


* Potential problems described below **
    # IP does not match:
    #                           IP from ifconfig: 172.xx.xxx.xx
    #   /etc/nginx/sites-available/bigbluebutton: 2xx.xxx.xxx.xx
    # Error: Unable to connect to port 1935 (RTMP) 2xx.xxx.xxx.xx

    # Error: Unable to connect to port 9123 (desktop sharing) on 212.xxx.xxx.xx
```

---

ls -l /var/freeswitch/meetings/

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 freeswitch daemon 5139984 Mar  6 11:44 488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675-81976383.wav
```

---

ls -l /usr/share/red5/webapps/video/streams/488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675/

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 red5 red5 438342 Mar  6 11:44 320x240-cztd6nyzasaz_1-1425642114164.flv
```

---

ls -l /usr/share/red5/webapps/video/streams/488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675/

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 red5 red5 438342 Mar  6 11:44 320x240-cztd6nyzasaz_1-1425642114164.flv
```

---

cat /usr/share/red5/webapps/video/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml

```
<bean id="web.handler" class="org.bigbluebutton.app.video.VideoApplication">
        <property name="recordVideoStream" value="true"/>
        <property name="eventRecordingService" ref="redisRecorder"/>
</bean>
```

---

cat /usr/share/red5/webapps/deskshare/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml

```
 <bean id="streamManager" class="org.bigbluebutton.deskshare.server.stream.StreamManager">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="true"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="recordingService"/>
 </bean>
```

---

bbb-record --watch

```
Every 2.0s: bbb-record --list20                                                                                                                                   Fri Mar  6 11:53:58 2015

Internal MeetingID                                               Time                APVD APVDE RAS Slides Processed            Published           External MeetingID
------------------------------------------------------  ---------------------------- ---- ----- --- ------ -------------------- ------------------  -------------------
57d9849193299cebe9409d1c98d175958331d34a-1425642748807  Fri 6 Mar 11:52:28 GMT 2015   X                  5
488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675  Fri 6 Mar 11:42:46 GMT 2015  XXX         X       6
```

---

bbb-record --debug

```
E, [2015-03-06T11:48:20.335578 #4548] ERROR -- : Sanity check failed on 488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675
```

---

cat /var/log/bigbluebutton/archive-488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675.log

```
# Logfile created on 2015-03-06 11:48:19 +0000 by logger.rb/31641
I, [2015-03-06T11:48:19.320704 #4550]  INFO -- : Archiving events for 488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675.
W, [2015-03-06T11:48:19.851280 #4550]  WARN -- : Failed to archive events for 488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675. Permission denied - /var/bigbluebutton/recording/raw/488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675/events.xml
I, [2015-03-06T11:48:19.851428 #4550]  INFO -- : Fetching the recording marks for 488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675.
I, [2015-03-06T11:48:19.851501 #4550]  INFO -- : Getting record status events
W, [2015-03-06T11:48:19.851585 #4550]  WARN -- : Failed to fetch the recording marks for 488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675. Permission denied - /var/bigbluebutton/recording/raw/488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675/events.xml
I, [2015-03-06T11:48:19.851645 #4550]  INFO -- : Archiving audio /var/freeswitch/meetings/488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675*.wav.
W, [2015-03-06T11:48:19.851920 #4550]  WARN -- : Failed to archive audio for 488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675. Permission denied - /var/bigbluebutton/recording/raw/488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675/audio
I, [2015-03-06T11:48:19.851981 #4550]  INFO -- : Archiving presentation for 488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675.
W, [2015-03-06T11:48:19.852257 #4550]  WARN -- : Failed to archive presentations for 488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675. Permission denied - /var/bigbluebutton/recording/raw/488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675/presentation
I, [2015-03-06T11:48:19.852322 #4550]  INFO -- : Archiving deskshare for 488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675.
W, [2015-03-06T11:48:19.852561 #4550]  WARN -- : Failed to archive deskshare for 488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675. Permission denied - /var/bigbluebutton/recording/raw/488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675/deskshare
I, [2015-03-06T11:48:19.852620 #4550]  INFO -- : Archiving video for 488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675.
W, [2015-03-06T11:48:19.852834 #4550]  WARN -- : Failed to archive video for 488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675. Permission denied - /var/bigbluebutton/recording/raw/488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675/video
```

---

all folder under /var/bigbluebutton/ have same rights (drwxrwxrwx tomcat7 tomcat7)

ls -l /var/bigbluebutton/

```
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 3 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Mar  6 11:42 488052dc7c095c74bf8992ec51a66298db04b765-1425642166675
drwxr-xr-x 3 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Mar  6 11:52 57d9849193299cebe9409d1c98d175958331d34a-1425642748807
drwxrwxrwx 2 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Mar  3 15:52 blank
drwxrwxrwx 2 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Feb 17 17:17 configs
drwxrwxrwx 2 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Mar  3 15:57 deskshare
drwxrwxrwx 2 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Mar  3 15:57 meetings
drwxrwxrwx 3 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Mar  3 15:52 playback
drwxrwxrwx 3 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Mar  3 15:57 published
drwxrwxrwx 6 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Mar  3 15:57 recording
drwxrwxrwx 2 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Mar  3 15:57 unpublished
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the product manager for BigBlueButton.

> Debian Wheezy (7.8) all is ok except archiving recordings...

We develop, test, package, and deploy BigBlueButton 0.9.0-beta on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.  We have not tested any other version of Ubuntu or Linux and, if you try, you may encounter problems.

Is it an option for you to install on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit?

Regards,... Fred

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer...the problem is that i don't like ubuntu ;-)..but if is the only solution I will try ..